# How to create a new index and add properties in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new for elastic search. I have installed and started elastic search in windows. now, how to create new index and how to add new properties in elastic search.

Comment: you should read the elasticsearch documentation. it is pretty good https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html

Comment: yes.they give curl command. How can i run curl command?.What is the procedure to run?

Comment: @Gopal please share whatever you have tried so far? We can help you on that.

Comment: i just the elastic search in windows. output:{
  "name" : "jMnIO2q",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "HU-gH-DTQ0aq20dnZcWeAg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.4.1",
    "build_hash" : "2cfe0df",
    "build_date" : "2017-05-29T16:05:51.443Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.5.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}. Now i have to add new index and properties. How to do?

Comment: I have curl command to create index and add property. my question is how to run the curl command.Is there any tool required to run curl command?

Comment: you can use sense which is a chrome plugin. curl is just a tool to help you do http requests to your elastic instance. You can also use Postman, or any other tool to create http requests, or write your own using javascript or other programming languages. I personally prefer sense because of the intellisense.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense-beta/lhjgkmllcaadmopgmanpapmpjgmfcfig

Edit: also you should read this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_talking_to_elasticsearch.html

Comment: can you please add any example to run query in sense

Comment: its the same as the examples in the elasticsearch documentation, just remove the curl-command if it is present.

PUT twitter
{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 3, 
            "number_of_replicas" : 2 
        }
    }
}

Comment: I highly recommend you to read this post http://joelabrahamsson.com/elasticsearch-101/ :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the solution with your help...